# JRE issue with TLauncher and JDK issue with Eclipse IDE

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

I just want to try asking here what is the solution with conflicting Java installers (JRE & JDK)

First is I have an Eclipse IDE which I used to practice coding and what comes with it is JDK 18 for it to run, and recently I installed TLauncher and it needs JRE 8 to run, which I eventually followed and it did work. However I cannot run Eclipse IDE anymore because it doesn't accept the version 8 of JRE that I installed for TLauncher, so for it to run once again, I have to manually install JDK 18 and it works, but not for TLauncher for this time (it says JRE 1.8.0 is needed)

So my situation is I have to install JRE 1.8.0 when it's time for me to play Minecraft and install JDK 18 after so I can code in Eclipse

Any solution so I can run both at the same time without installing javas?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to:

1. Install both java versions (8 & 18)
2. Set your PATH and JAVA_HOME pointing to java 8 (so TLauncher, whatever that is, works) so any "non-configurable" applications default to that.
3. Modify your `$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse.ini` to point to the java 18 install folder (reference: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini). Add these two lines:

```
    -vm
    C:\your-path-to-java18\bin\javaw.exe
```

That way, you will have Java8 by default in your system, allowing you to run TLauncher, while Eclipse will launch using the Java 18 version.

You may also need to properly configure eclipse to use the correct JDK and language level in your projects from within its preferences.